# Custom response after success authentication spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I need to send back a response with user's GrantedAuthority after success authentication instead of redirecting to successPage.
How can I do this with spring?

Comment: Where do you want to send it back to?

Comment: From server to client's browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler. Check out the this [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login).